# Which MAC address is used in UuidCreateSequential?

Tags: c++, windows

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-uuidcreatesequential), UuidCreateSequential reportedly uses the MAC address of the machine's Ethernet card.

If the computer has several Ethernet adapters, which address will be used?

Comment: Why does it matter? It's just used as a way to help make the uuid globally unique, and for that it doesn't really matter which MAC address is selected.

Comment: Probably the first. The actual hardware or BIOS might influence the order hardware is reported in.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It matters to my particular situation. I'm working with software that uses the end of the UUID to retrieve the machine's MAC, and compares it to another MAC for validation purposes. I would like to understand how the API chooses which adapter to retrieve the MAC from, in order to avoid breaking the validation when another adapter is added.

Comment: @MSimon I fully respect that that's what you are working with, but I have to say that it seems like a really bad idea...